# APEX 5: Horizontal Scollbar on page instead of region

Tags: oracle-apex

I'll generate in APEX 5 (Universal Theme) a large table with PL/SQL Dynamic Content.

To scroll down, there is a scrollbar on the page. To scroll to the right, there is only a scrollbar in the region/div. 
So if user want to see the values in the most right column in the first rows, they have to scroll all down, move to the right and scoll all up.

Thats very anoying.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by enabling the "Maximize Button" for the Region.

Answer (score 0):

Region template must be interactive report region 
and must set to attribute style="overflow-auto;"